# How do you make VLookup return a Zero for entries not in the list in Excel 2010?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup

Short version: I'm using Excel 2010 and using VLookup to extract data from a properly-sorted table with 3-digit numerical entries in  column 1, and pertinent data in column 2. Some 3-digit numbers do not appear int he list. Whenever I try to reference a number not in the list, I get the last-existing-found number's data, and I want a zero.

Details: On Sheet1, I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

Note that 125, 127, and 128 are missing.

On Sheet2 I have a variety of things sorted by another method, but that each have a corresponding 3-digit code that matches that table:

[image]

In column 3, I'm using **=VLOOKUP(R38,Table4[#All],2)**, and you can see it mostly works. But when the 3-digit number isn't present in the data table, such as 125 and 127, it gives me the matching entry for the last number before the missing one. That doesn't work.

I need the cell to be empty, or to be able to return a pre-determined value to indicate it's empty, ideally zero (because that fits better with my actual project).

Notes:

- Adding all 3-digit numbers to the data table is not an option, as I cannot manipulate that table.
- The result must be the same for any item that is missed. It would ALWAYS be zero, though "blank" is acceptible if necessary.

How can I accomplish this *without using macros* and only using formulas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R38,Table4[#All],2,0),0)
```

where the zero at the end if the `VLOOKUP` calls for an exact match, then the `IFERROR` replaces the #N/A result of the mismatch with the Zero you are looking for.

Comment: This gave me the answer, but not for the "IFERROR" part, actually. I wasn't using the 4th (optional) input of VLOOKUP at all, so it was defaulting to "approximate match," which I didn't realize. Seeing your use of zero in that spot made me look harder at what it did. I had used IFERROR without it before, with no success, because there's no error on an approximate match. Your complete formula line led me to the right answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your formula in =IFNA() or =IFERROR()